# Check it List of objects contains string

Tags: java

here is my function

```
private static List<Types> getShiftTypes() {

    List<Types> types = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String shift : shifts_arr_t) {

        if (!types.contains(shift)) {

            types.add(new Types(shift));
        }

    }

    return types;
}
```

Types:

```
public class Types 
{
String type;
int count;

public Types(String type) {

        this.type = type;

}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object)
{
    boolean sameSame = false;

    if (object != null && object instanceof Types)
    {
        sameSame = this.type == ((Types) object).type;
    }

    return sameSame;
}
}
```

But the compare override is not working. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: You have two mistakes in your implementation: you check `String`s for reference equality, and you override `equals` without overriding `hashCode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot compare bananas and apples.

Here :

```
    if (!types.contains(shift)) {
```

types refers to a `List of Type` and `shift` refers to a `String`.
Besides  to make it working your `equals()` method should compare a `String` with a `Type`. Which is not a good idea as it could never be reflexive.

In your case, you don't need to override equals()/hashCode(), create instead of a method that iterates on `types` and return true or false according to the `String` to test equals to the `Type` field value of any elements in `types`.
Or as a straighter  alternative use a stream with a `Predicate` such as :

```
private static List<Types> getShiftTypes() {

    List<Types> types = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String shift : shifts_arr_t) {

        if (types.stream().anyMatch(t -> t.getType().equals(shift))) {    
            types.add(new Types(shift));
        }

    }

    return types;
}
```

Comment: That's an excellent catch, in addition to the other mistakes in OP's code.